# FreeMarker cannot seem to parse HTML 5 data-* atttributes

Tags: freemarker

I wrote a simple custom directive, and have it pass all attributes through as regular element attributes. The syntax of the tag as follows:

```
<@link_to controller="unobtrusive" action="do-get" data-target="result">Do Get</@>
```

Unfortunately, I get an exception:

```
Caused by: freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "-" at line 32, column 56 in unobtrusive/index.ftl.
Was expecting:
    "=" ...
```

This is because it cannot seem to parse "data-target" attribute. When I change it to "data_target" with the underscore, all is fine.... but I really would need the dash: "-".

Can someone help?

Thanks,

Igor

Answer (score 2):

As of 2.3.22, you can use `-` (and `.` and `:`) as part of any name if you precede it with a `\`, like in `<@link_to  data\-target=...>`. (It's not too cute, but `-` is already used as subtraction operator, and fixing this wouldn't backward compatible, and so must wait for a major FTL version increase.)

Comment: thanks for fixing  it. Seems to be working. However IntelliJ 14.1.2 flags this as an error. Is there a chance to fix this syntax in IntelliJ?

Comment: You should report this to whoever maintains that plugin (JetBrains, I guess). As a temporal workaround, maybe they call Freemarker to check template syntax, in which case you could manually replace the `freemarker.jar` that the plugin uses.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the - but in that context it's not being used as an HTML tag, it's an FTL argument for a custom directive.  FTL doesn't like dashes in variable names apparently, but that won't prevent you from including the dash in the output.

You didn't include your directive, but I think what your trying to accomplish might look like this.  Just write your link in the macro, referencing the data_target as ${data_target}.  Notice the result has data-target as output.

```
<#macro link_to controller action data_target>
     Here is the controller: ${controller}  
     Here is the action: ${action}
     Here is the data-target: ${data_target}
</#macro> 

<@link_to controller="unobtrusive" action="do-get" data_target="result"></@>
```

Comment: Andy, thanks for quick reply, but this is not helping. I wrote it not as macro, but as a Java class. IN any case, I could do underscore, which works, but this is not what I need. I need a dash: "-"

Comment: Freemarker is a template langauge, and knows nothing of HTML.  Yes freemarker is often used to produce html, but it doesn't parse it, and it certainly would never be tripped up because of some html feature.