# FreeMarker cannot seem to parse HTML 5 data-* atttributes, chokes on dash

Tags: html, freemarker

I wrote a simple custom directive, and have it pass all attributes through as regular element attributes. The syntax of the tag as follows:

`<@link_to controller="unobtrusive" action="do-get" data-target="result">Do Get`

Unfortunately, I get an exception:

`Caused by: freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "-" at line 32, column 56 in unobtrusive/index.ftl.
Was expecting:
    "=" ...


This is because it cannot seem to parse data-target` attribute. When I change it to "data_target" with the underscore, all is fine.... but I really would need the dash: "-".

Can someone help?

Thanks,
Igor

Comment: possible duplicate of [FreeMarker cannot seem to parse HTML 5 data-* atttributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938374/freemarker-cannot-seem-to-parse-html-5-data-atttributes)

Comment: Note that 2.3.22 gives a solution for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28950479/606679

Answer (score 0):

Try this tip from the [FAQ](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/app_faq.html#faq_strange_variable_name)

<`@link_to controller="unobtrusive" action="do-get" "data-target"="result">`

I haven't tried this personally so can't vouch if it will work.

Comment: this did not work, I get <code>Was expecting one of:
    ";" ...
    <ID> ...
    ">" ...
    <EMPTY_DIRECTIVE_END> ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    "(" ...
</code>, however, I solved this problem by not using this construct. Thank you for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

I just stuck in the same problem. <@form.textarea ... data-maxCount="100" />. It seems that freemarker misinterprets special characters in names... [Freemarker FAQ](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_strange_variable_name)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2.3.22, you can use `-` (and `.` and `:`) as part of any name if you precede it with a `\`, like in `<@link_to  data\-target=...>`. (It's not too cute, but `-` is already used as subtraction operator, and fixing this wouldn't backward compatible, and so must wait for a major FTL version increase.)